# Facebook Login API "Can't load URL" from file:///

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, oauth, facebook-login

I have searched thoroughly and cannot find any answer to my question - so either it's really complicated, I'm being stupid, or I'm doing something architecturally wrong.

What I am trying to implement is logging in to my app with the Facebook API, and I am having some trouble. The aim is to open a Facebook login window using their API in Cordova, let the user login, and then redirect back to the webapp in Cordova.

The problem comes when making the Facebook OAUTH call. Cordova serves the index from `file:///android_asset/www/index.html`. I believe this is where the conflict lays. Upon opening the Facebook login URL, I receive:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I have my Facebook app settings set up to localhost, and the call works if served from a server, i.e. `localhost:PORT/index.html`.

Can anybody help to get it working from the Cordova container?

[image: Facebook app settings]
[image: Facebook app settings]

Comment: You probably need to modify your webserver (apache/nginx) config to make the folder `android_asset/www` publicly accessible

Comment: I don't believe that answers the question he was asking. Cordova serves the file from that address, period. There's no changing that. If he were serving this from a web server that would been possible.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: Is there any solution regard the same ?